# Powershell - Insert into MySQL database table errors?

Tags: mysql, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I have this insert query that's not inserting properly and is really annoying. I will explain briefly what I tried and what I actually want to achieve.

What my PS script does:

1. ping every computer from a database table
2. if ping succeeds, get username logged on from the computer
3. insert to database table the following values : username, hostname, online(true/false)

Now here are the problems that keep showing up.

**Problem 1: If I use the following command:**

$username =  Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $workstation -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username;

It will insert the username values like so: **SUPER/user1** which is Okay but I want to get rid of the "SUPER/" and just keep the actual username "user1" before inserting.

I tried using the one below but it doesnt work:

```
 $username =  Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $workstation -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty -replace '^.*\\'  Username;
```

The command in **problem 1** will give me these TWO errors:

**Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the 
value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.**

And

**Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable.**

How can I ignore those two errors?

I hope someone can help me out because its really annoying. thanks in advance everyone.

**Powershell script:**

```
foreach($pcname in $workstation_list){

        $command = $connection.CreateCommand();
        $command.Connection  = $connection;
        $command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO workstation_userlogged
                                 (username,hostname,online)
                                 VALUES (@username,@hostname,@status)";

        ### ============================================================= 
        ### values to be assigned as a parameters
        ### =============================================================           
        $workstation = $pcname;                
        $test_ping   = Test-Connection -ComputerName $workstation -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        $status      = [bool](Test-Connection $workstation -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue);

        #if status is TRUE get username
       if($test_ping)
        {
            $username = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $workstation -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username;
            echo $username;
           #echo -replace '^.*\\' $username;         

           #if ping succeeds but no user is logged
           if($username -eq "") 
           {
                $username = "no user logged";  
           } 

        } #end if

        #if ping DOES NOT succeed set username value to NULL and status to FALSE
        elseif(!$test_ping)
        {
            $username = [DBNull]::Value;
        }

       ### ============================================================= 
       ### Assign parameters with appropriate values
       ### ============================================================= 
        $command.Parameters.Add("@username", $username)     |   Out-Null
        $command.Parameters.Add("@hostname", $workstation)  | Out-Null
        $command.Parameters.Add("@status",   $status)       | Out-null
       ### ============================================================= 
       ### Execute command query
       ### ============================================================= 
        try{
            $command.ExecuteNonQuery() | out-null;
            Write-Host "Successfully inserted in Database";
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host "Caught the exception";
            Write-Host "$_";
        }

       ### ============================================================= 
       ### clear parameter values
       ### =============================================================  
         $command.Dispose()
         $workstation = "";
         $username    = "";
         $status      = "";
         $test_ping   = "";
     }#end for each loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two things.  first, this line:

```
$username = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $workstation -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Username #-ExpandProperty
```

Should probably be this:

```
$username = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $workstation -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username
```

Second, you didn't use any quotes when embedding the username variable in the SQL String.  Try this.  I quoted all three values since I don't know what types the other columns are.

```
$command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO workstation_userlogged
                                    (username,hostname,online)
                                    VALUES ('$username','$pc_db','$ping_status')";
```

Comment: +1 The domain part can be removed from the username like this: `$Username -replace '^.*\\'`

Comment: the reason why I removed **-ExpandProperty** is because it keeps giving me this error : **Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.**

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I tried to do it but gives me **}** at the end? What am I doing wrong? thanks. I updated my code above

Comment: @mario The parameter `-ExpandProperty` expects exactly one argument: the name of the property you want to expand, so you **MUST** use `select -Expand property`. Using `select property -Expand` will **NOT** work. And you get the trailing `}`, because you didn't expand the property before removing the domain part.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers guys I updated the content and code above. I tried what you guys told me but no luck.. please help. thanks in advance

Comment: it won't insert a null because you are using strings.  You should really be using parameters.  here's my really old blog post on how to do that.  It's using SQL Server instead of MySQL, but you should be able to make it work: http://powershellstation.com/2009/09/15/executing-sql-the-right-way-in-powershell/

Comment: @mario I already told you to use `-replace '^.*\\'` to remove the domain part from `$username` (after you expanded the property `Username`). Ignore problem 2, because it's already solved by expanding the property `Username`. And I guess you're getting problem 3, because you put the variable `$username` between quotes in your SQL statement. If you need to be able to insert NULL values as well, you'll need a [parametrized query](http://powershellstation.com/2009/09/15/executing-sql-the-right-way-in-powershell/). Which you should be using anyway.

Comment: will try what you guys told me and let you know as soon as I get it working, thanks for the help its appreciated!

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I updated my code and mentioned the reoccurring errors. Hope any of you can help.. thanks again

Comment: After you get $username, do this:
`$username=$username -replace  '^.*\\'
The RPC error means that you're having trouble accessing the WMI registry on one of the remote servers.  Troubleshooting that issue is a different story altogether.  Looks like you did the parameters thing correctly at first glance.